# How to display image using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, image

How can I display the image in the following div `id="image"` using jQuery

**HTML:**

```
<h3 style="clear:both" class="margin_top30">Images</h3>
            <div class="contentSection">
                <div id="image"> </div>
            </div>
```

**jquery:**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            var id = window.location.search.substring(1);
            id = id.replace('id=','');
            var url = "http://localhost/schoollife/services/author_chapter.php?a=image&id="+id;
            //alert(url);
            $.ajax({
               url:url,
               success:function(result){
                  var obj = $.parseJSON(result);
                  var table = "<table>";
                  for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {

                     table += "<tr>"
                     table += "<td><img src='http://img/"+obj[i].image_file_name+"' style='margin-right:20px;' /></td>";

                     table += "</tr>";
                     table +="<tr><td colspan='3'>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
                  }
                  table += "</table>";
                  $("#image").html(table);

                }   
              });
            })
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is not working? What is the PHP code you are using?

Comment: use `<img />` tag... i think the src in your script is not correct.. thus image is not displayed

Comment: nothing is wrong with the above code, check your link that you pass in `SRC`

Comment: can you send me any link how to display image using jquery

Comment: `'http://img/"+obj[i].image_file_name+"` I think this should be without `http`, like `'/img/"+obj[i].image_file_name+"` or `img/"+obj[i].image_file_name+"`

Comment: Are you trying to call up a PHP file from localhost?

Answer (score 1):

You rather rely on $.getJSON as it makes your code saying what you want to achieve with $.ajax - retrieving JSON-formatted data from a remote source. And check your server side code if it provides a valid JSON. Here is a working example:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
      var url = "./author-chapter.json";
      $.getJSON( url, function( data ){
            var out = "<table>";
            $.each( data, function( i, row ) {
               out += "<tr>";
               out += "<td><img src='" + row.image_file_name + "' style='margin-right:20px;' /></td>";
               out += "</tr>";
               out +="<tr><td colspan='3'>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
            });
            out += "</table>";
            $("#image").html( out );
      });
  });
```

Controller (author-chapter.json)

```
[
  {"image_file_name": "./slides/sample_fussen.jpg"},
  {"image_file_name": "./slides/sample_keukenhof.jpg"}
]
```

P.S. If you want to control exceptional behavior - just go with deferred methods - .done, .fail instead of the callback